# CGAL, Cropped voronoi diagram confined in a rectangle

Tags: c++, cgal, voronoi

I'm using CGAL with Qt to draw Voronoi diagram. I used `CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DT,AT,AP>`since I need the faces. This is the example code:

```
for(Face_iterator f = VD.faces_begin(); f != VD.faces_end(); f++)
    {
        Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec_start = (f)->ccb();
        Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec = ec_start;
        do {
            if (!ec->has_source())
            {
            }
            else
                QpolyF << QPointF(((Halfedge_handle)ec)->source()->point().x(), ((Halfedge_handle)ec)->source()->point().y());
        } while ( ++ec != ec_start );
        VectPolygon.push_back(QpolyF);
        QpolyF.clear();}
```

I need to clip the rays that has source or target in infinity. If I use the Cropped_voronoi_from_delaunay to generate voronoi it only gives the segments not the faces.    these are the typedefs:

```
typedef K::Line_2                                           Line_2;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K>                   Delaunay_triangulation_2;
typedef Delaunay_triangulation_2::Face_iterator             dt_Face_iterator;
typedef Delaunay_triangulation_2::Edge_circulator           dt_Edge_circulator;

// typedefs for defining the adaptor
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                  K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K>                                    DT;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<DT>                 AT;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<DT> AP;
typedef CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DT,AT,AP>                                    VD;


// typedef for the result type of the point location
typedef AT::Site_2                    Site_2;
typedef AT::Point_2                   Point_2;

typedef VD::Locate_result               Locate_result;
typedef VD::Vertex_handle               Vertex_handle;
typedef VD::Face_handle                 Face_handle;
typedef VD::Face_iterator               Face_iterator;
typedef VD::Halfedge_handle             Halfedge_handle;
typedef VD::Ccb_halfedge_circulator     Ccb_halfedge_circulator;
```

Comment: Why aren't you happy with the following example: 
http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_37.5.4 ?

Comment: As I said I need faces,but that example in CGAL only gives segments.

Comment: There is also the "2D Range and Neighbor Search" which comes pretty close, but I'm not sure whether it supports this query, even via passing a specific functor. http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Point_set_2/Chapter_main.html

Comment: There is Unbounded_face_iterator for the unbounded faces. Is it possible to find intersection of those unbounded faces with rectangle? The problem is how to define the unbounded faces as polygon or an object to check intersection.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's possible to do it with CGAL, but I found a workaround for now. in Qt, QPolygon class has the function to find intersected polygons. `Qpolygon::intersected(yourPolygon)`.
this is the results:

[image: Voronoi diagram cropped to a rectangle]

Comment: Source code would have been quite helpful in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is some experimental code here: http://code.google.com/p/cgal-voronoi-cropping that crop a voronoi diagram to a rectangle, the result being a HDS. See main.cpp in the test directory

Answer (score 2):

The following will generate a random point cloud, find its Voronoi diagram, crop that diagram to the cloud's bounding box, and generate well-known text polygons.

I'm not sure how to integrate this with Qt, but, presumably, once you have the polygons this part will be easy(ish).

```
//Finds the cropped Voronoi diagram of a set of points and saves it as WKT
//Compile with: g++ main.cpp -Wall -lCGAL -lgmp
//Author: Richard Barnes (rbarnes.org)
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Regular_triangulation_filtered_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Regular_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Regular_triangulation_adaptation_policies_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Regular_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>
#include <CGAL/bounding_box.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

//Used to convert otherwise infinite rays into looooong line segments
const int RAY_LENGTH = 1000;

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Regular_triangulation_filtered_traits_2<K>  Traits;

typedef CGAL::Regular_triangulation_2<Traits> RT2;
typedef CGAL::Regular_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<RT2>         AT;
typedef CGAL::Regular_triangulation_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<RT2> DRP;
typedef CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<RT2, AT, DRP> VD;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::vector<RT2::Weighted_point> wpoints;

  std::cout.precision(4);
  std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);

  //Generated random points
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    //Weight of 0 gives a Voronoi diagram. Non-zero weight gives a power diagram
    wpoints.push_back(RT2::Weighted_point(K::Point_2(rand()%100,rand()%100), 0)); 

  //Find the bounding box of the points. This will be used to crop the Voronoi
  //diagram later.
  const K::Iso_rectangle_2 bbox = CGAL::bounding_box(wpoints.begin(), wpoints.end());

  //Create a Regular Triangulation from the points
  RT2 rt(wpoints.begin(), wpoints.end());
  rt.is_valid();

  //Wrap the triangulation with a Voronoi diagram adaptor. This is necessary to
  //get the Voronoi faces.
  VD vd(rt);

  //CGAL often returns objects that are either segments or rays. This converts
  //these objects into segments. If the object would have resolved into a ray,
  //that ray is intersected with the bounding box defined above and returned as
  //a segment.
  const auto ConvertToSeg = [&](const CGAL::Object seg_obj, bool outgoing) -> K::Segment_2 {
    //One of these will succeed and one will have a NULL pointer
    const K::Segment_2 *dseg = CGAL::object_cast<K::Segment_2>(&seg_obj);
    const K::Ray_2     *dray = CGAL::object_cast<K::Ray_2>(&seg_obj);
    if (dseg) { //Okay, we have a segment
      return *dseg;
    } else {    //Must be a ray
      const auto &source = dray->source();
      const auto dsx     = source.x();
      const auto dsy     = source.y();
      const auto &dir    = dray->direction();
      const auto tpoint  = K::Point_2(dsx+RAY_LENGTH*dir.dx(),dsy+RAY_LENGTH*dir.dy());
      if(outgoing)
        return K::Segment_2(
          dray->source(),
          tpoint
        );
      else
        return K::Segment_2(
          tpoint,
          dray->source()
        );
    }
  };

  //First line of WKT CSV output
  std::cout<<"\"id\",\"geom\"\n";

  int fnum = 0;
  //Loop over the faces of the Voronoi diagram in some arbitrary order
  for(VD::Face_iterator fit = vd.faces_begin(); fit!=vd.faces_end();++fit,fnum++){
    CGAL::Polygon_2<K> pgon;

    //Edge circulators traverse endlessly around a face. Make a note of the
    //starting point so we know when to quit.
    VD::Face::Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec_start = fit->ccb();

    //Current location of the edge circulator
    VD::Face::Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec = ec_start;

    do {
      //A half edge circulator representing a ray doesn't carry direction
      //information. To get it, we take the dual of the dual of the half-edge.
      //The dual of a half-edge circulator is the edge of a Delaunay triangle.
      //The dual of the edge of Delaunay triangle is either a segment or a ray.
      // const CGAL::Object seg_dual = rt.dual(ec->dual());
      const CGAL::Object seg_dual = vd.dual().dual(ec->dual());

      //Convert the segment/ray into a segment
      const auto this_seg = ConvertToSeg(seg_dual, ec->has_target());

      pgon.push_back(this_seg.source());

      //If the segment has no target, it's a ray. This means that the next
      //segment will also be a ray. We need to connect those two rays with a
      //segment. The following accomplishes this.
      if(!ec->has_target()){
        const CGAL::Object nseg_dual = vd.dual().dual(ec->next()->dual());
        const auto next_seg = ConvertToSeg(nseg_dual, ec->next()->has_target());
        pgon.push_back(next_seg.target());
      }
    } while ( ++ec != ec_start ); //Loop until we get back to the beginning

    //In order to crop the Voronoi diagram, we need to convert the bounding box
    //into a polygon. You'd think there'd be an easy way to do this. But there
    //isn't (or I haven't found it).
    CGAL::Polygon_2<K> bpoly;
    bpoly.push_back(K::Point_2(bbox.xmin(),bbox.ymin()));
    bpoly.push_back(K::Point_2(bbox.xmax(),bbox.ymin()));
    bpoly.push_back(K::Point_2(bbox.xmax(),bbox.ymax()));
    bpoly.push_back(K::Point_2(bbox.xmin(),bbox.ymax()));

    //Perform the intersection. Since CGAL is very general, it believes the
    //result might be multiple polygons with holes.
    std::list<CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<K>> isect;
    CGAL::intersection(pgon, bpoly, std::back_inserter(isect));

    //But we know better. The intersection of a convex polygon and a box is
    //always a single polygon without holes. Let's assert this.
    assert(isect.size()==1);

    //And recover the polygon of interest
    auto &poly_w_holes = isect.front();
    auto &poly_outer   = poly_w_holes.outer_boundary();

    //Print the polygon as a WKT polygon
    std::cout<<fnum<<", "
    "\"POLYGON ((";
    for(auto v=poly_outer.vertices_begin();v!=poly_outer.vertices_end();v++)
      std::cout<<v->x()<<" "<<v->y()<<", ";
    std::cout<<poly_outer.vertices_begin()->x()<<" "<<poly_outer.vertices_begin()->y()<<"))\"\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For an unbounded face, is it possible to avoid using `RAY_LENGTH`? Because, I think, if the size of the rectangle is awkward and/or if the angle between two rays are large, then even with big `RAY_LENGTH` the resulting crop may still leave out the corner area.